# select statement from 2 unrelated tables

Tags: mysql

There's 2 unconnected tables, with no common IDs

```
+---------------------+
| names               |
+------+--------------+
| name        | lastN |
+-------------+-------+
| Anthony     | monta |
| Ryo         | shizu |
+------+--------------+

+----------------------+
| nicknames            |
+------+---------------+
| nickname             |
+------+---------------+
| miso_hungry          |
+------+---------------+
```

I'm trying to run a select query on both tables and currently doing something like:

```
SELECT names.name, nicknames.nickname
FROM names, nicknames
WHERE names.name="miso_hungry" OR nicknames.nickname="miso_hungry"
```

I'm getting back a weird results with repeating identical rows, which doesn't make sense.

For example if I search for miso_hungry with the query above it will return every row of "names" table for some reason and append the correct rows from the "nicknames" table..

Attaching a screenshot of the results

[image]

Above should show "NULL" under name column, since "miso_hungry" is not found in that column and I'm not sure why it prints every row of the "names" table also.

Comment: This makes no sense, maybe you should read some basic SQL tutorial. Can you post your expected output?

Comment: There's nothing weird here. A basic introduction to relational databases may prove instructive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can use UNION Clause**

- Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns
- The columns must also have similar data types
- The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order

So we need to made them satisfy above condition. We can use Aliasing to do this.

```
SELECT name,(SELECT NULL) as nickname FROM names WHERE name = "miso_hungry"

UNION

SELECT (SELECT NULL) as name, nickname FROM nicknames WHERE nickname = "miso_hungry"
```

---

**Edited**

If you want to get the match count from both table use query like below :

```
SELECT SUM(count) as count FROM ( 
    SELECT count(*) as count FROM names WHERE name = "miso_hungry"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(*) as count FROM nicknames WHERE nickname = "miso_hungry"
) both_table
```

Comment: thank you for the information, the problem in my case is that the 2 tables have different amount of columns , so the first SELECT would be searching through one column whereas the second one would search through multiple

Comment: @RobertSinclair you can add any number of column in the where clause.

Comment: You just have to make sure, you select same number of column and same name and type

Comment: it's in the SELECT clause where i would have a problem. My whole goal is to just see which table contains my search value, so can I do something like SELECT COUNT(*) FROM and do a union?

Comment: What result do you want then ?

Comment: just a count of 0 or 1, that confirms that the 'search term' is found in one of the 2 tables.

Answer (score 1):

The order of execution in your statement is from,where,select. With and implicit join you get a cartesian product which given

```
use sandbox;
create table n(name varchar(20));
create table nn(nickname varchar(20));

insert into n values('Antony'),('Ryo');
insert into nn values('miso');
```

results in

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT n.name, nn.nickname
    -> FROM n, nn;
+--------+----------+
| name   | nickname |
+--------+----------+
| Antony | miso     |
| Ryo    | miso     |
+--------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The where clause is then applied - which yields the same result.

Comment: thank you for the info, i guess i ended up with a cartesian join